# How can I query Dynamodb for different hash keys and secondaryindex?

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to do log table in dynamodb and my table looks like

> **Pid[HashKey] || TableName[SecondaryIndex] || CreateDate[RangeKey] || OldValue || NewValue**
>
> 10 || Product || 10.10.2013 00:00:01 || Shoe || Skirt
>
> 10 || Product || 10.10.2013 00:00:02 || Skirt || Pant
>
> 11 || ProductCategory || 10.10.2013 00:00:01 || Shoes || Skirts
>
> 19 || ProductCategory || 10.10.2013 00:00:01 || Tables || Armchairs

Pid = My main db tables primary key

TableName = My main db table names

CreateDate = Row created date

now I want to get list of

> where (Pid = 10 AND TableName = "Product") OR (Pid = 11 AND
>   TableName="ProductCategory")

in a single request (it wouldn't be so short like this. It could include too many tables and pids)

I tried batchget but I didn't use it because I couldn't query with secondary index. It needs rangekey with equal operator.

I tried query but this time I couldn't send multiple hash key in a same query.

Any ideas or successions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the OR .... Generally you cannot get this where condition with a single query operation without modifying your row,

**Solution 1:** You have to issue 2 query operations, and append them to the same resultset.

```
where (Pid = 10 AND TableName = "Product")

union

where (Pid = 11 AND TableName = "ProductCategory")
```

Those operations should run in parallel to optimize performance.

**Solution2:** create a field xxx that describe your condition and maintain it on writes, than
you could create a [global secondary index](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) on it and perform a single query.

Comment: First solution creates 20 burst query if I want to get log data of 20 tables change log.

Comment: Second solution that I didn't exactly understand. But secondary global index on another field doesn't solve anything. Because my target is prevent from bursts query.